# Weird inheritance pattern

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Suppose I have a base class like this:

```
class Abstract {
  public:
    /* This type should be the deriver of this class */ 
    virtual DerivedType foo(void) = 0;
};
```

And I want `DerivedType` to be different depending on who derives from this class.  In fact I want `DerivedType` to be the type that `Derives` from `Abstract`.

I realize that I could do something like this:

```
template<typename der_t>
class Abstract {
  public:
    virtual der_t foo(void) = 0;
};
```

And then it should be used like this:

```
class Derived : public virtual Abstract<Derived> { };
```

Unfortunately there is no way to force someone to pass in the right type in the template.  That is someone could do this:

```
class Derived : public virtual Abstract<int> { };
```

So is there any better way to do this, or is there a way to force someone to pass in the right parameter?

Comment: What you want to get is similar to the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). I dont have much experience with that, but it seems common to assume a user will put the right template parameter.

Comment: Why is it *unfortunate* that the user of the template can pass a "wrong" (I'd rather say different) type? I find that it makes the pattern more general and flexible. Even though the case where a different type is needed might be rare.

Comment: I think you can use static asserts for checking the relationship, but before adding code that enforces a particular use I would consider what the worst thing that could happen would be, and if the thing that could happen would perhaps even be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual trick for CRTP's is to have a private constructor that only the passed-in class can access via a `friend` directive:

```
template <class Derived>
struct Crtp {

private:
    friend Derived;

    Crtp() = default;
};
```

It isn't perfect, but guards against errors.

Note : `static_assert`ing is not a practical solution, because at the time `Crtp` is instantiated `Derived` is still incomplete, and can't be checked for base classes.

Comment: `friend Derived;` - great trick, didn't know you could friend a template parameter.